# Inkscape: how to draw cased lines, or filled shapes with strokes that have their own fill

Tags: inkscape, line-art

How to create a circle or any other shape whose perimeter line is *cased*? That is the stroke has it's own interior fill and bounding line in addition to the shape having fill?

I can simulate it by stacking 2 circles, with the inner circle smaller and centre occluding the outer circle, but this is extra work and grows less and less feasible on complex shapes. I was hoping to find a line/stroke style that does this all in one go, leaving the objects as single entities.

[image: example]

These example shapes are visually correct, but they're they're result of drawing, duplicating, resizing and then grouping multiple objects.

Another phrasing of this question: How to create a *stroke paint* that is smaller or with an inner offset to it's *stroke style*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- create your shape
- give it a stroke
- select PATH >> STROKE TO PATH
- You now have a new shape that has the form of your path to which you can apply a stroke and fill to.

Comment: Ok, this works well with lines, thanks. When I do it with a filled shape though, the shape loses it's fill when it's stroke is converted to a path. I figure out a workaround of duplicating the circle first and then converting the dupe's stroke to path; not sure that's the best route? Also how to save the path-stroke-style so it can be readily re-applied with exact settings to multiple objects? (perhaps that a new Q?)

Comment: @mattwilkie not sure I follow your workaround, but in general, if it works for you, go for it! As for applying to multiple objects, you can use SHIFT+CNTL+C and V to cut-and-paste the style of one object to another (I find that a huge time saver)